# Serialization of classes containing generics with backwards compatibility

Tags: c#, serialization, backwards-compatibility

I am trying to find out the best way to handle serialisation in my program.

I want to serialize private fields (so XML serializer is no option)
I want to serialize generic types like Bindinglist (SoapSerializer is no option)
I also want to provide some level of support for being able to deserialize object from previous versions of my program.

So all I think I am left with is the BinarySerializer, and implementing the ISerializable interface to cope with forward compatibility.

Is this correct?

Note: 
I must say I found this project. 
However the project seemed dead and I couldn't get it working (file missing error)
http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=196509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `BinaryFormatter`, you can use [`[OptionalField]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.optionalfieldattribute.aspx), but this is still [very brittle](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html).

How about [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)? Does all that, and doesn't have the versioning issues associated with BinaryFormatter. Since it is based on Google's "protocol buffers" format, it is **designed** to be version tolerant and extensible (disclosure: I'm the author, so I may be biased).

Alternatively, `DataContractSerializer` supports field serialization; just set `[DataMember]` against your fields instead of the properties (requires .NET 3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd need to implement ISerializable.

The key points are the following

- Implement GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context). Here you need to add key pairs into info object.
- Implement serialization constructor MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context). Here you'd need to get the values from the info object.